# What is the explanation of R28///// in METAR?

Tags: metar, meteorology

In an Aviation Routine Weather Report (METAR), what is the explanation for `R28/////` in the RVR section? `R28` stands for Runway 28 followed by visibility in meters. But still, I am curious as to why 5 forward slashes are used instead of 4?

Source:

> Indira Gandhi International Airport (IGI), Delhi, India METAR report on 5th Jan, 2022 21:30IST (GMT +5:30)
> `VIDP 051600Z 13009KT 1500 R28///// R29/2000 RA BKN030 OVC080 13/13 Q1016 NOSIG=`

Answer (score 5):

From NOTAM

> Q) VIDF/QFTAS/I/NBO /A /000/999/3006N07544E
> A) VIDP
> B) 22/01/05 14:16 C) 22/01/06 12:00
> E) INSTRUMENTAL RVR OF RWY 28-TDZ NOT AVBL DUE TECHNICAL FAULT AT SITE.

From @randomhead

> but my guess (from looking at the R29 RVR value) is that the first slash is part of R28/ (similar to R29/2000) and the four slashes after that replace the actual reported number.